# Can I mount fully encrypted HDD from another HDD? (TrueCrypt)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

I have two HDDs. One with Windows 7 installed, another with Ubuntu. The first one is fully encrypted with TrueCrypt while the other one with Ubuntu is not.

HDD A -> Win7, encrypted
HDD B -> Ubuntu, not encrypted

**Can I get access (read/write) to the files on A from B?**

I've installed both OSs separately (installed Win7 on A while B was unplugged and Ubuntu on B while A was unplugged).

Comment: I think yes. You should mount A from Ubuntu through TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Install truecrypt on ubuntu and either mount the volume or fully decrypt it.